# При клике по одному элементу кликнуть другой в пределах этого же li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для имитации клика по одному элементу при клике на другой я использую

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.swatch-label').attr('data-id', function(index) {
  return '' + (index + 1);
})
$('.vsps-dot-color-selected').attr('data-id', function(index) {
  return '' + (index + 1);
})
$(document).on('click', '.swatch-label', function() {
    $('.vsps-dot-color-selected[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').click();
});
</script>
```

- задаю id и потом кликаю.
  Но это неправильно для меня работает когда в одном li нет какого-то из элементов или их больше ( например swatch-label два элемента а vsps-dot-color-selected три штуки, т.е. нет точного соответствия по числу ) и тогда все ломается,
  Как это решить чтобы это работало для каждого li, чтоб так сказать пересчет осуществлялся в каждом li заново. ?

```html
<-- это упрощенная разметка -->
   <li class="retw">
<div class="vsps-slider-container">
    <span class="vsps-dot vsps-dot-color-selected vsps-active"  data-id="1">что-то5</span>
    <span class="vsps-dot vsps-dot-color-selected"  data-id="2">что-то1</span>
</div>
<div class="jcsmw-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_ves">
      <span class="swatch swatch-label swatch-100g selected" title="100 г" data-value="100g" data-id="1">100 г</span>
      <span class="swatch swatch-label swatch-25g " title="25 г" data-value="25g" data-id="2">25 г</span>
</div>
</li>
```

Т.е. надо чтоб при клике на **.swatch-labe**l кликался **.vsps-dot-color-selected**, но каждый на свой так сказать

Answer (score 0):

Как-то вопрос сложно закручен, не ясно ничего.

```
$('.swatch-label').on('click',function(){

    let data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    let current = $('.vsps-dot-color-selected[data-id="' + data_id + '"]');

    console.log($(current).html());
});
```

надеюсь вы это имели ввиду..

*UPD:*

```
$('.swatch-label').on('click',function(){
    let data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    let current = $('.vsps-dot-color-selected[data-id="' + data_id + '"]');
    $(current).click();
});

$('.vsps-dot-color-selected').on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ищем внутри тега и получаем первый элемент:

```
$($(this).parent().parent().find('.vsps-dot-color-selected[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]')[0]).click();
```

Но лучше перед кликом сохранить элемент в переменную и проверить есть ли такой вообще